# Applying for US H4 visa when I have a valid B1 visa

Tags: usa, dependent-visa, h4-visa

I have a valid B1 visa. My spouse is holding an H1 visa and I would like to go as a dependent [H4]. If I apply for an H4 now will it invalidate my B1 visa?